# VBA: Copy columns E, F, and G, paste data below data in B, C, D. Repeat for every 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am looking to move a hundred or so columns in one sheet to the first 3 columns in the same sheet. I would like to take the columns in E,F,G, paste them below the data in B,C,D and then take columns H, I, J and paste them at the bottom of B, C, D (Which now includes the data from E, F, G. repeating this procedure for every 3 columns until the end of the data. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub OneColumnV2() 

Dim iLastcol As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim jLastrow As Long
Dim ColNdx As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim ExcludeBlanks As Boolean
Dim mycell As Range

ExcludeBlanks = (MsgBox("Exclude Blanks", vbYesNo) = vbYes)
Set ws = ActiveSheet
iLastcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Alldata").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets.Add.Name = "Alldata"

For ColNdx = 1 To iLastcol

  iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColNdx).End(xlUp).Row

  Set myRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, ColNdx), _
                       ws.Cells(iLastRow, ColNdx))

  If ExcludeBlanks Then
     For Each mycell In myRng
        If mycell.Value <> "" Then
           jLastrow = Sheets("Alldata").Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
                      .End(xlUp).Row
           mycell.Copy
           Sheets("Alldata").Cells(jLastrow + 1, 1) _
              .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
     Next mycell
  Else
     myRng.Copy
     jLastrow = Sheets("Alldata").Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
                .End(xlUp).Row
     mycell.Copy
     Sheets("Alldata").Cells(jLastrow + 1, 1) _
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
Next

Sheets("Alldata").Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Delete

ws.Activate
End Sub
```

I believe the problem is occurring in the definition of 'iLastcol' instead of xlToLeft, the column range should encompass 3 columns there.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include any code you've tried?

Comment: no problem, posted.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` (it only is serving to hide issues in your code - in this case) then  [debug your code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) and you will most likely solve the issue. If you still cannot solve, update your question with a [mcve] of the exact issue you face.

Comment: The syntax is not the issue, it is the output of the code. I'd like it to be dynamic enough to move from cluster to cluster after pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing, so I wrote this based on what you asked in your question. It should do what you want. Just a note on excluding blank cells, it will change the alignment of every 3 columns cells with each other when you copy over. I'm not sure if that's intended or an oversight. So I haven't included that in the below code, but you can easily incorporate it in if you wish

```
    Sub moveColumnsData()

    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim destLastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sourceRng As Range
    Dim destRng As Range
    Dim a As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

        'loop through every set of 3 columns
        For i = 5 To lastColumn Step 3
            sourceLastRow = .Range(.Columns(i), .Columns(i + 2)).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            'incase columns BCD are blank then set last row=1
            Set a = .Columns("B:D").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not a Is Nothing Then
                destLastRow = a.Row + 1
            Else
                destLastRow = 1
            End If

            'no need to use copy/paste, just let the range equals to each other
            Set sourceRng = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(sourceLastRow, i + 2))
            .Cells(destLastRow, "B").Resize(sourceRng.Rows.Count, sourceRng.Columns.Count) = sourceRng.value

        Next

        'uncomment below to clear all columns besides BCD
        '.Range(.Columns("E"), .Columns(lastColumn)).Clear
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: This is better as it avoids the .Selects, multiple runs, implicit worksheets for ranges, and full cell copies of the other answer but some quick comments... 1) There is no reason to perform a Find for the last row in B:D every iteration. Just add `destLastRow = destLastRow + sourceLastRow` at the end of the loop. 2) I think `sourceLastRow = ` will throw an error if there is a chunk of 3 columns with no data (data in HIJ but not EFG). 3) IMO the traditional `.Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row` is cleaner so maybe that in a `LastRow` function and a function that calls that 3x and gets max.

Comment: Thank you! Worked smoothly. Only question is regarding 'i = 5', why is set to 5 and not 3?

Comment: @WillKennedy That loop is iterating through the columns that have to move (column E and beyond). Column E is the 5th column so the first iteration of the loop takes columns 5-7 or E-G and then we `Step` 3 columns to columns 8-10 or H-J.

Comment: Got it, so if I wanted to manipulate the code  to copy 1,2, or 4 columns. Would this number and the code `Columns( i + 2)` in the following be the only parts that needed to be updated?

Comment: @WillKennedy Yes though it would be easier to see if you defined those as variables. `For i = firstColToCopy To colsPerChunk` and next row `i + 2` -> `i + colsPerChunk - 1` etc

Answer (score 0):

**Hey there,** not a clean solution but its quite functional and works like a charm! `CopyAdjDataUnderMyTable()`

Every time you run this function you will copy the 3 adjacent columns (EFG) and move it below BCD as in the example.

```
Sub CopyAdjDataUnderMyTable()

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 2)).Select

    'MsgBox (Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count)

        If Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count = 3 Then
        Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(1, 0)).Select
        Else
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        End If

    Selection.Cut
    Range("B1").Select

      'MsgBox (Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count)

        If Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count = 1 Then
        Selection.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Else
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        End If


    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B1").Select

   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 2)).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

   Range("B1").Select


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: set your code to loop over every 3 columns, that way you don't have to keep clicking

Comment: There appears to be a slight error as columns headers are copied to column A.

Comment: @WillKennedy changed `Range("A1").Select` to `Range("B1").Select` so the gif represents the code. Thanks for pointed it out.